# JAVA - calculator no if's or catch - ScriptEngineManager

Tags: java

As my school job I have to write a calculator (args passed with command line) without any conditional operands such If, catch or for, while, etc.

I want to use a JavaScript to do the calculation, but my problem is that I get the java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String.

Please help me to correct my code.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Calc {

    public String doCalc(String string) {

        String[] argsList = {};
        BigDecimal a = null, b = null;
        String operand = null;

        try {
            argsList = string.split("\\s+");
            a = new BigDecimal(argsList[0]);
            operand = argsList[1];
            b = new BigDecimal(argsList[2]);

            //JavaScript arithmetics
            ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            //JavaScript arithmetics

            return (String) engine.eval(a+ " " + operand + " " + b);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("wrong args");
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: `return Integer.toString(engine.eval(a + " " + operand + " " + b));`

Comment: nice but I get "The method toString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)"

Comment: I forgot to write that I need BigDecimal

Comment: Blurp, forgot to read the docs. `eval()` returns an `Object` and not an `Integer`. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String))

Comment: Why use JavaScript for the calculation? Just use a `switch/case` statement (it's not in your "not allowed" list).

Comment: unfortunately 'switch/use' is not allowed

Comment: attention: my code is NOT CALCULATING BigDecimals !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `toString();` appended to the return line seems to do the trick.

The line becomes:

```
return engine.eval(a+ " " + operand + " " + b).toString();
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String)) the `eval()` method returns an (unspecified) Object, of which the `toString()` method seems to convert the result properly.